# Atom Editorでfind and replaceを閉じれない

Tags: atom-editor

Atom editorで検索や置き換えをするためにCmd-fでfind-and-replaceを開いた後、Escを押しても閉じることができません。

どうすれば閉じられるのでしょうか?

OS: macOS 10.12.4
Atom: 1.16.0

Comment: find-and-replaceの検索窓をクリックするなどしてそのタブにフォーカスした後 Escキーを押してもタブを閉じることができないということでしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu はい、そのような状況です

Comment: 追加で入れたパッケージが影響してるのではないでしょうか。前vim-mode-plusで同じ様な事がありました

Answer (score 0):

Command Palette を開いて下記コマンドを実行すれば検索Windowを閉じることができませんか？

`find-and-replace:Toggle`